# Maximum number of routings for n points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I'm trying to formulate an equation to calculate the maximum number of routings possible for a given amount of points, with the following rules or restrictions:

- A route must contain atleast one point
- A point can be visited only once per route

An example with 2 points, A & B:
The 4 valid routes:

- only visit A
- only visit B
- first A, then B
- first B, then A

I'm assuming this would be

```
2! + 2 = 4 valid routes
```

For 3 points, I'm able to describe 15 valid routes, and the formula could be

```
3! + 3! + 3 = 15 valid routes
```

Can I assume that for 4 points, the formula would be 4! + 4! + 4! + 4 = 76? EDIT: No, 4 points results in 64 valid routes

Is it possible to create a dynamic formula with variable X?

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such questions.

Answer (score 3):

Given n points.

There are 2^n subsets from these points. And every subset has a number of permutations. You can create this by e.g.:

```
routings[n_] := 
  Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[Range[n], {1, n}], 1]  // Length;
```

Now e.g.:

```
routings[4]
```

You may create an integer sequence and look it up in OEIS the online encyclopedia of integer sequences:

[link to integer sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%204%2C%2015%2C%2064%2C%20325%2C%201956%2C%2013699%2C%20109600%2C%20986409%2C%209864100&language=german&go=Suche)

There you find several formulas for the number of routings. E.g.

```
a = 1; Table[a = (a - 1)*(n - 1); Abs[a], {n, 0, 40}]
```